# Custom push notification sound via UNNotificationServiceExtension

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'd like to be able to specify a url for a custom notification sound in my payload and have that sound be played for that notification. From what I've read, I need to download the sound file to the App's Library/Sounds folder -- but I don't seem to have access to that from the service extension. I tried using a shared container but I still only appear to have access to the Library/Caches folder there -- and I doubt even if I could get the file to the shared Library/Sounds folder it would work.

So, has anyone found a way to use a custom sound file on-the-fly for push notifications?

Comment: It's been a while, curious if you figured this one out!  I have a similar use case

Comment: For mobile applications, especially on iOS, the ability to play a custom notification sound typically requires the sound file to be bundled with the app's package and referenced appropriately in the notification payload. This means you generally cannot download and play a custom sound on-the-fly directly from a URL for a push notification due to sandboxing and the security model of iOS.

Comment: Basically You want to play a different sound on different payload you have to put all files in package and on behalf of payload you can trigger that sound from the package.